# How do I remove nearby places when embedding google map in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-maps

I want to embed the following map on my website:

https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=67+Bridge+Street,+Chester&hl=en&sll=53.16379,-2.737316&sspn=0.678421,2.113495&oq=67+bridge+&hnear=67+Bridge+St,+Chester+CH1+1NW,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=16

The map has a marker for the desired address but then it also has markers for nearby places like Costa coffee, Eastgate clock etc.

Is there a way to embed the map without markers for any other places on it?

Just to clarify I want to keep the big red marker but remove all the other places of interest and businesses

Comment: Do you wanT to remove the marker on the maP...

Comment: Can you show me the exact location you want to show and witch markers you don't want to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Map api allows developer to control its appearance, refer to [syntax styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

> **Map Features**: A map consists of a set of features, such as a road or park, which are
>   specified using a MapTypeStyleFeatureType. The feature types form a
>   category tree, with all as the root. The full list of features for
>   selection within a map is documented in the Maps [Javascript API V3
>   Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType). Specifying the feature as all will select all map elements.

`google.maps.MapTypeStyleFeatureType` includes many values for feature types, i.e. `road.labels, landscape.natural, poi.business`,
in your case, the way to hide other business place, here is an example to achieve:

```
var styles = [
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "business",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write a little Javascript to make that happen. Check the Google Maps site on styling here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Specifically check out this paragraph on that resource:

> Style Array Example
>
> The map feature selectors and the styler rules are combined into a
>   style array. Any number of features can be targeted in a single array.
>
> The following example turns all map features to gray, then colors
>   arterial road geometry in blue, and **hides business labels
>   completely**

There is an example of that code immediately below it. Hope that helps.